# Circuit redraw. Series and parallel resistors

Tags: parallel, series

I just wanted to ask you if I redrew the circuit correctly and if you could help me what to calculate first or if you could help me to redraw this circuit even simpler. And to tell me a few tips for knowing if resistors are in parallel or series.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  A simpler answer is shown bellow, which is closer to the given question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fns1Et.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For R1, pivot on B and pull rest of circuit to straighten out R1.

Pivot on D to straighten out R3.